# Store traefik let's encrypt certificates not as json

Tags: ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, traefik

you know traefik is able to do all the Let's Encrypt stuff (request and renew) for your webservices. But traefik stores the requested certificates as a JSON-file, which isn't the common format for certificates.

I want to use the Let's Encrypt certificates also for my mail-server, so I need them in simple format: *.pem or *.crt.

Here my question: Is it possible that traefik stores the Let's Encrypt certificates in a common format?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 9):

I'm using `jq` to do this

*export certificate*

```
cat acme.json | jq -r '.Certificates[] | select(.Domain.Main=="'www.example.com'") | .Certificate' | base64 -d > www.example.com.crt
```

*export private key*

```
cat acme.json | jq -r '.Certificates[] | select(.Domain.Main=="'www.example.com'") | .Key' | base64 -d > www.example.com.key
```

#### Traefik with Consul as KV store

*export JSON containing certificate and private key*

```
consul kv get traefik/acme/account/object | gzip -dc | jq -r '.DomainsCertificate.Certs[] | select(.Domains.Main=="'www.example.com'") | .Certificate' > www.example.com.json
```

*export certificate only*

```
consul kv get traefik/acme/account/object | gzip -dc | jq -r '.DomainsCertificate.Certs[] | select(.Domains.Main=="'www.example.com'") | .Certificate.Certificate' | base64 -D >  www.example.com.crt
```

*export private key only*

```
consul kv get traefik/acme/account/object | gzip -dc | jq -r '.DomainsCertificate.Certs[] | select(.Domains.Main=="'www.example.com'") | .Certificate.PrivateKey' | base64 -D > www.example.com.key
```

#### backup Consul

*backup*

```
consul kv get -base64 traefik/acme/account/object > backup-base64
```

*restore*

```
cat -s backup-base64 | base64 --decode | consul kv put traefik/acme/account/object -
```

Answer (score 2):

The most popular solution is [`ldez/traefik-certs-dumper`](https://hub.docker.com/r/ldez/traefik-certs-dumper). In case of `docker-compose` you need something along the following lines:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
    traefik:
        image: traefik:1.7
        command:
            --entryPoints='Name:http Address::80'
            --entryPoints='Name:https Address::443 TLS'
            --defaultentrypoints=http,https
            --logLevel=DEBUG
            --docker
            --docker.exposedByDefault=false
            --acme
            --acme.acmeLogging=true
            --acme.entrypoint=https
            --acme.storage=/data/acme.json
            --acme.onHostRule=true
            --acme.httpChallenge.entryPoint=http
        ports:
            - 8001:80
            - 8002:443
        volumes:
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
            - .:/data

    traefik-certs-dumper:
        image: ldez/traefik-certs-dumper:v2.7.0
        entrypoint: sh -c '
            apk add jq
            ; while ! [ -e /data/acme.json ]
                || ! [ `jq ".Certificates | length" /data/acme.json` != 0 ]; do
                    sleep 1
                ; done
            && traefik-certs-dumper file --watch 
                --source /data/acme.json --dest /data/certs'
        volumes:
            - .:/data

    # test service
    whoami:
        image: containous/whoami
        labels:
            traefik.enable: true
            traefik.frontend.rule: Host:example.com
```

`traefik` ports are published to `8001` and `8002`. I assume here that you need certificates as separate files because you want to put `traefik` behind another proxy.

[more](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/fe1805dd4f4118aa649ea650d0df9a4a)

Comment: It's the only thing that works thanks! How come that apk add jq is not part of the Dockerfile? There is probably a way to streamline all that muliline command into an entrypoint.sh

Comment: @Firsh-justifiedgrid.com It's been a while since I used `traefik` and friends, so I'm not sure if `jq` should be part of the image (you generally don't want to add stuff that is not often needed). But you can certainly slim down the `traefik-certs-dumper` part by extracting most of it into a `Dockerfile`. And generally that would be a better way.

Comment: Just had the idea since it's a custom image to begin with and jq and those commands are vital/needed for its operation. Not like it has any other purpose, so why not.

Comment: @Firsh-justifiedgrid.com I understand you think that `ldez/traefik-certs-dumper` should come with `jq` preinstalled. To decide it we need to know how often `jq` is needed with this image. Why? It's one of the [`docker` best practices](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#dont-install-unnecessary-packages) I'm no judge here since I don't even remember how it all works. You might be right, or not. I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I'm new to Traefik, so there might be a better solution than this that I'm not aware of.

What I've done is used [a Python script by JayH5](https://gist.github.com/JayH5/f9e4dc48635f3faa63c52813ff6d115f) to extract the keys files from the acme.json file.

```
def read_domain_certs(acme_json_path, domain):
    with open(acme_json_path) as acme_json_file:
        acme_json = json.load(acme_json_file)

    certs_json = acme_json['DomainsCertificate']['Certs']
    domain_certs = [cert['Certificate'] for cert in certs_json
                    if cert['Domains']['Main'] == domain]

    if not domain_certs:
        raise RuntimeError(
            'Unable to find certificate for domain "%s"' % (domain,))
    elif len(domain_certs) > 1:
        raise RuntimeError(
            'More than one (%d) certificates for domain "%s"' % (domain,))

    [domain_cert] = domain_certs
    return (base64.b64decode(domain_cert['PrivateKey']),
            base64.b64decode(domain_cert['Certificate']))
```

Depending on your use case, you could skip saving the files and load the keys directly from the JSON file using that code. However, if you do need the PEM files, the script does also writes the key contents, if you need the files on disk.

```
def write_cert(storage_dir, filename, cert_content):
    cert_path = os.path.join(storage_dir, filename)
    with open(cert_path, 'w') as cert_file:
        cert_file.write(cert_content)
    os.chmod(cert_path, 0o600)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party but meanwhile there are some dockerized solutions that will extract the certificates for you and watch the `acme.json` file for changes, e.g. https://github.com/SnowMB/traefik-certificate-extractor (I'm not affiliated in any way with it).

Comment: As always there is an obvious answer :)

Comment: Doesn't work for Traefik 2